# Outer join and unique records in each table

Tags: sql

```
TableA
------
IntId   EvId    Name    Phone1
=====   ====    ====    ======
100     aaa     xxx     11111
101     bbb     yyy     22222
102     ccc     zzz     33333
103     bbb     asd     44444
104     bbb     sdf     55555


TableB
------
IntId   ASId    Grp     Phone2
=====   ====    ====    ======
201     bbb     yyy     6666
202     ccc     zzz     7777
203     bbb     asd     8888
204     bbb     kkf     9999
205     ddd     esd     0000
206     eee     ffr     1001
```

I want to join TableA with TableB using `TableA.EvId = TableB.ASId` to output `{IndId, EvId, Name, Phone1, Grp, Phone2}` (using outerjoin as I want all records in TableA with matching TableB columns)
I could do it using below query, but it is giving me duplicates since EvId and ASId have duplicates.

```
SELECT a.IntId, a.EvId, a.Name, a.Phone1, b.Grp, b.Phone2
    FROM TableA a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB b
    ON a.EvId = b.ASId
```

If EvId are duplicates, consider that record which has max IntId. Same rule for TableB

My final output should be like this - all unique EvId's in TableA using outerjoin on B

```
IntId   EvId    Name    Phone1      Phone2      Grp
100     aaa     xxx     11111       null        null
104     bbb     sdf     55555       9999        kkf
102     ccc     zzz     33333       7777        zzz
```

Can you please help me with the query?

Comment: First write two queries that makes them unique based on your rules. Then join those two subtables. The query that makes them unique depends on the type of database server. Please edit the question and add the tag for the type of database server. MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? Postgres?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT a.IntId, a.EvId, a.Name, a.Phone1, b.Grp, b.Phone2
FROM TableA a LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT b.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ASId ORDER BY IntID DESC) as seqnum
      FROM TableB b
     ) b
    ON a.EvId = b.ASId AND b.seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Hello Gordon, thankyou for the help! When I try to execute this in sql server, it says `Invalid column name 'seqnum'`. Since table a doesn't have seqnum, i guess it is giving that. My tables are in sqlserver. Also, there's a where clause at the end, but when i put where statement, it says `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'` Can you please help me clarify.

Comment: Hello Gordon, when i remove a before a.seqnum=1, its working but its not removing duplicates on tableA, it is only removing duplicates on tableb